# Integrating Forums in Django

Tags: django, forum

I am pretty new to the coding world and django, I am pretty far along within a site and I would like to add a forum function

does anyone have suggestions, I am currently using 1.8.2

I was able to get spirit working on its own, but could not figure out how to integrate it. I also tried djangobb, but the same as spirit.

any help would be great

Comment: Questions to recommend a tool are not in general allowed in SO. Having said that, take a look at https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/forums/

Comment: write your own...define the model first then design the template and write the view function along with url .. just like that ..

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Pybbm](https://github.com/hovel/pybbm). It is fully documented and easy to customize.

Comment: @SudheerK Update log say compatible ith python 3 here: https://github.com/hovel/pybbm/blob/master/docs/updates.rst#0149---015 but for specific python 3.5 you should ask to them.